# Изменение id элемента вставленного в HTML с помощью js "на ходу"

Tags: javascript

есть такой код:

```js
let countOfFields = 0;
let curFieldNameId = 0;

function addField() {
  countOfFields++;
  curFieldNameId++;
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = "<input name='text_' + curFieldNameId + '' type='text' placeholder = 'Имя человека'> <br> <input id='example2' type='range' min='1' max='20' step='1' + curFieldNameId + '' onchange='textbox2.value = example2.value'/> <input id='textbox2' type='text' /> <button onclick='return deleteField(this);' href='#'>-</button>";
  document.getElementById("parentId").appendChild(div);
  return false;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="return addField()" href="#">+</button>
<div id="parentId">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Имя человека">
  <br>
  <input id="example1" type="range" min="0" max="20" step="1" onchange="textbox1.value = example1.value" />
  <input id="textbox1" type="text" />
  <br>
</div>
```

мне нужно что бы значение цифры у textbox менялось динамично, то есть - при добавлении textbox 2, в следующее добавление поля в HTML оно увеличивало значение textbox и example на один.

Comment: В чём сейчас проблема?

Comment: в том что я не понимаю как это реализовать

Comment: а что это за код такой? что он делает? или копипаст с интернета?

Comment: этот код вставляет в дом поля с range инпутом

Comment: Мне кажется id менять не совсем правильно. А вот аттрибут data- элемента можно

Comment: покажете пример? просто я в веб-разработке новичок

Comment: "этот код вставляет в дом поля с range инпутом " --- так и в чём **с ним** проблема? ты же его сам написал или что? вон у тебя есть `countOfFields` и `curFieldNameId` так что "я не понимаю как это реализовать" --- какая-то ложь

Comment: да, сам. просто мне нужно что бы Id менялся при вставлении нового поля, а я не имею представления как это реализовать

Comment: надо инициализировать переменные `countOfFields` и `curFieldNameId` за пределами функции, и уже в функции их прибавлять. тогда они будут хранить зачение за пределами функции

Comment: так я уже инициализировал. просто забыл сюда вставить. я не представляю как менять именно внутри вставляемого хтмл кода

Comment: значит у тебя строка не так сформирована....у тебя там бардак с кавычками..... ты пытаешься вставить переменную через `+` при этом строка не закрыта двойными кавычками перед ней и также надо опять заново после +  открывать **двойные** кавычки..... вот разберись с этим и должно работать

Comment: здесь апостроф с клавиши ~`<input name='text_${curFieldNameId}' type='text' placeholder = 'Имя человека'> <br> <input id='example${countOfFields}' type='range' min='1' max='20' step='1' onchange='textbox${countOfFields}.value = example${countOfFields}.value'/> <input id='textbox${countOfFields}' type='text' /> <button onclick='return deleteField(this);' href='#'>-</button>`здесь апостроф с клавиши ~

Comment: спасибо, должно работать!